# convert sql to entity framework syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am a beginner in EF, would you please help me to convert below SQL to EF:

```
WITH TopRows AS (
    SELECT [MId]
      ,[SId]
      ,[Index]
      ,[Capacity]
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                         PARTITION BY [MId] 
                         ORDER BY [Index]
                   ) AS [ROW NUMBER]
      FROM [dbo].[myTable]
)
SELECT * FROM TopRows
WHERE TopRows.[ROW NUMBER] <= [Capacity]
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: When you wrote the SQL, there was some requirement that you tried to fulfill. Something like: give me the values of properties MId, SId, Index, Capacity from the rows of MyTable that ... Can you give us this requirement. i'm not really familiar with `Over / Partition`

Comment: What did you try until now, what were the problems with these approaches?